# TextInputLayout doesn't refresh the hint

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to implement the new widget from the new Design API, TextInputLayout, and I have a problem: first, I load the layout in a fragment, then, when I click on a button and want to change the hint of the TextInputLayout, nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout;
Button button;
onCreateView(){
    ...
    textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout);
    button = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    textInputLayout.setHint("Abc");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            textInputLayout.setHint("Xyz");
        }
    });
}
```

something like this. I need, somehow, to refresh the textInputLayout to get the new hint.

Hope I made myself clear.

Thank you for your help!

UPDATE: The Android Developers team made an update and the TextInputLayout is working properly now when setting the hint to the TextInputLayout widget.

Answer (score 0):

Does the first setHint("abc") work ?

Because if you check method for the new TextInput : [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html), they are the same.
So the setHint must work..

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer. Yes, it works. I tried with invalidate() and a lot of other solutions, but nothing made it work. I need to refresh the hint. Bad bad bad widget :D But awesome in the same time.

Comment: the second works only when you trigger the animation.